# Where is the database for the built in user part of asp.net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

User registration/authentication seems to be built into MVC2 but where does is the database that stores the users? It's not under data connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database is first created when you create the first user for the website. After that the .mdf file is in app_data folder.

If you want it to be shown in VS, you can click Project -> Show all files and then it should be visible in Solution Explorer. Right click ASPNETDB.MDF and click Include in project.

Comment: I marked this one as correct because it showed me how to add it into the project. Darin Dimitrov's answer was informative too though.

Answer (score 3):

The default template uses SQL Express edition. An `aspnetdb.mdf` file will be stored in the `App_Data` directory. Look at the connection string in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks. The contents of the app_data directory don't show up in VS. Is there any way I can open it in VS like what would be done with a normal database created within VS?

Comment: By default when you create a new ASP.NET MVC project there's no contents in this directory. It is empty. It is up to you to manually create the database using the [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) tool.

Comment: I just wanted to add the exisiting aspnetdb database which has the membership info. I was able to do this by right-clicking on the app-data and adding existing source in VS.

Answer (score 3):

u don't have to use aspnet_regsql.exe tool - just start your app, register new user, and then open the app_data directory in windows explorer - u will find your db file over there

Arek

Answer (score 0):

App_Data folder